# Listen to selection range changes

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a mobile web application (Sencha Touch 2) in which the user can fill in a number field with an amount. The first time the user enters a number, a currency symbol is added at the end of the field

Now, what I would like to do is preventing the user from moving the cursor to the end of the field and deleting the currency symbol.

I'm already reseting the selection range when the input gets focus like this :

```
input.setSelectionRange(ln, ln);
```

But I don't know how to know when the user moves that cursor (the field is already focused)

Is there an event that's fired on the input then ?
Or is there any other way to find out ?